# processing.data java package loadStrings(); getJSONObject

Tags: java, package

I am not able to find the `.jar` for processing data
I am trying to use the functions 
`loadStrings();` and 
`getJSONObject();`

but I can find the package

Comment: If you know in which class they are defined you can use services like [findJar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x) to find a matching jar file name. otherwise the name of the framework these methods belong to might give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the jar you're after is java-json.jar
You can download it form,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm